# Finding result in a PHP Array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I'm trying to find out all of my "Likes" from a mysql table and to put them into an array but I'm really not sure if I'm doing it right as I keep getting a "Wrong Datatype" error.
Here is my code:

```
<?php
$check_like_sql = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE type = 'Like' && poster = '$yourid'";
$check_like_res = mysqli_query($con, $check_like_sql) or die (mysqli_error());
if(mysqli_affected_rows($con)>0){
    while($likes = mysqli_fetch_assoc($check_like_res)){
        $yourlike = $likes['media'];    
    }
    $likearray = mysqli_fetch_array($con, $yourlike); 
}
?>
<?php
if(in_array($likearray, $postid)) {
            $likethis = "<a href=\"php/unlike.php?poster=$yourid&post=$postid\">Unlike</a> . ";
        }
        else if($posttype == "Like"){
            $likethis = "";
        }
        else{
            $likethis = "<a href=\"php/like.php?poster=$yourid&lat=$yourlat&lon=$yourlon&like=$postid&user=$postusername\">Like</a> . ";
        }
?>
```

Could anyone please explain where there might be an error?  I'm very new to this sort of php coding. Thanks

Comment: Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, object given in --- on line 8

Warning: in_array() [function.in-array]: Wrong datatype for second argument in --- on line 47

Comment: What are you trying to do with `mysqli_fetch_array($con, $yourlike);` ? see [mysqli_fetch_array](http://php.net/manual/fr/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php)

Comment: what is in `$postid` ?? and from where the value is assigned

Comment: @Brewal I want to get all of the posts that I have "Liked" so that when they are shown I can choose to have either a Like or Unlike button depending on what I have already chosen

Comment: You  have looped around all the returned records from the SQL. Then once you have finished you are trying to use mysqli_fetch_array to return another record

Comment: `$yourlike` is not `mysqli_result`. Check my answer below

Comment: Actually, there are several mistakes in your code. Could you please give your table structure of `posts` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overriding `$yourlike` so first initialise it. Also there is no need for `mysqli_fetch_array` remove that part.

```
$yourlike = array();
if(mysqli_affected_rows($con)>0){
    while($likes = mysqli_fetch_assoc($check_like_res)){
        $yourlike[] = $likes['media'];    
    }
    //$likearray = mysqli_fetch_array($con, $yourlike);  // remove this part
}
```

**Edit**

Change this

```
if(in_array($likearray, $postid))
```

to

```
if(in_array($postid , $yourlike))
```

Comment: Thanks, this has cleared up the first error but what do I now do about `if(in_array($likearray, $postid)) {`?

Comment: I think that if(in_array($yourlike, $postid, true)) is batter

Comment: @user2516546 Post the error. Without knowing that we can't help you out.

Comment: I did - It's Warning: in_array() [function.in-array]: Wrong datatype for second argument in C:\--- on line 47

Comment: @user2516546 Ohh yeah it should be `if(in_array($postid , $yourlike))`. See edited answer also.

Answer (score 0):

`$yourlike` is not `mysqli_result`.

Replace this line

```
$likearray = mysqli_fetch_array($con, $yourlike);
```

with this one

```
$likearray = mysqli_fetch_array($con, $check_like_res);
```

Answer (score 0):

you are using mysqli_fetch_array incorrecty. The first argument is the result the second is the type to return

```
$result = mysqli_fetch_array($query_result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

however it looks like you are using it incorrectlyu as you have already fetched an assoc, can you not just delete the line
    $likearray = mysqli_fetch_array($con, $yourlike);

and change

```
$yourlike = $likes['media'];
```

to

```
$yourlike[] = $likes['media'];
```

and

```
if(in_array($likearray, $postid)) {
```

to

```
if(in_array($yourlike, $postid)) {
```